# Visio VBA export to PNG in high resolution?

Tags: vba, png, visio

I am trying to export pages to PNG from Visio, in high resolution.

When I export manually with a custom resolution of 300x300, I get dimensions of 3450x2397.

When I export with VBA with the syntax below, I get dimensions of 1104x767.

Where is the hitch? In the Application.Settings lines, I started out with just the first line, then added the others later, but it still does not work.

Edit: what is particularly infuriating is that this used to work. I even fetched an older version of the macro file from git, that I generated hi-res images with, and now they produce normal res images (3 figures instead of 4 in the dimensions).

```
...
pngPathName = pngPath & "\" & visioPage.name & ".png"
Debug.Print ("visioPage.Export " + pngPathName)
' set resolution to 300dpi
Application.Settings.SetRasterExportResolution visRasterUseCustomResolution, 300#, 300#, visRasterPixelsPerInch
Application.Settings.SetRasterExportSize visRasterFitToSourceSize, 2.208333, 2.135417, visRasterInch
Application.Settings.RasterExportDataFormat = visRasterInterlace
Application.Settings.RasterExportColorFormat = visRaster24Bit
Application.Settings.RasterExportRotation = visRasterNoRotation
Application.Settings.RasterExportFlip = visRasterNoFlip
' Export the page as an PNG file
visioPage.Export pngPathName
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Application and visioPage weren't on the same page. Application was referring to the file where the macro is located, visioPage to the file I was saving as PNG. This is inside a loop where I was processing all the files in a folder.

This is what I did to solve the problem:

```
Set visioDoc = visioApp.Documents.Open(visioPath)
...
visioDoc.Application.Settings.SetRasterExportResolution visRasterUseCustomResolution, 300#, 300#, visRasterPixelsPerInch
...
visioDoc.Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Export filePath
```

So I guess the moral is, in Visio VBA, to beware of the Application object, particularly when copy-pasting lines of code from the Macro recorder.